# Winform User Settings Location Changes Based On Program Location

Tags: c#, winforms, settings, appdata

I have a winform application (C#) which uses a settings file to store roaming user data.
I've written all the settings save functionality to happen at form close.
It all works OK but I've noticed that when the application closes it creates a users settings folder in AppData\Roaming\Manufacturer.... which is combination of the App Name and some random long sting of characters,
and if you move the application to a different folder it generates a completely new settings folder.
Why does it do this?

Example Folders from AppData.

- GenESL.exe
- GenESL.exe_Url_hgy40v2e24fd3mlmk0czttzy4vx1hsth
- GenESL.exe_Url_5kahw1xsec53k3jlh544wu2dehp4zzcd

Comment: What method are you using to save the settings?

Comment: I'm using a regular properties settings file and using the save method.  **Settings.Default.Save();**